# How to customise the UINavigationBar that appears when there are too many UITabBar items?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

The main thing that I'd like to change is the tint of the UINavigationBar that appears in the "More" item of a UITabBar.  I've done this for other NavigationControllers in normal items, but I haven't found where the one in the More item is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file that owns the tab bar controller insert the following:

```
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```